# Blank screen after Nvidia-340 install. Linux Mint XFCE 19.2

Tags: linux-mint, xfce, nvidia, nouveau

I've been using UBUNTU for the last 10 years.

For the first time, I'm using Linux Mint XFCE 19.2 in a laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad T61) with NVIDIA graphics card (G86M - Quadro NVS 140M). I wanted to install the proprietory drivers and After searching askubuntu.com and Linux mint forums, I came up with two nice comprehensive posts for nvidia-driver installation:

1. [Black screen at boot after nvidia driver installation on Ubuntu 18.04.2-LTS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwifzLqO4bzoAhW4wjgGHQE7Db0QFjACegQIBRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Faskubuntu.com%2Fquestions%2F1129516%2Fblack-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts&usg=AOvVaw266oTm0w8sUEuBxYHb7IDl)
2. [How do I install the nvidia drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Even after following the instructions very carefully and rebooting atleast a dozen times in the process, I ended up with a blank screen. Even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> doesn't bring up the console. Now, I've purged `nvidia-340` and boot by selecting "Advanced Options" and then the 1st option (*not recovery mode*). I have not removed the   `blacklist-nouveau.conf` and `nouveau-kms.conf` in `/etc/modprobe.d/` (Which I created as per the instructions of Marmayogi in Link 1 (as above)).

```
krishna@krishna-ThinkPad-T61:~$ ls /etc/modprobe.d/
alsa-base.conf          blacklist.conf           blacklist-framebuffer.conf  blacklist-nouveau.conf  blacklist-rare-network.conf  iwlwifi.conf
blacklist-ath_pci.conf  blacklist-firewire.conf  blacklist-modem.conf        blacklist-oss.conf      dkms.conf                    nouveau-kms.conf
```

The contents of the `.conf` files are as follows:

**blacklist-nouveau.conf**

```
krishna@krishna-ThinkPad-T61:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat blacklist-nouveau.conf 
# Disable default NOUVEAU driver
# ------------------------------
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

**nouveau-kms.conf**

```
krishna@krishna-ThinkPad-T61:/etc/modprobe.d$ cat nouveau-kms.conf 
options nouveau modeset=0
```

**My `inxi` output** is as shown below:

```
krishna@krishna-ThinkPad-T61:~$ sudo inxi -FG
System:    Host: krishna-ThinkPad-T61 Kernel: 4.15.0-54-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 7665AL6 v: ThinkPad T61 serial: L3M0834 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 7665AL6 serial: VF17B82K12T BIOS: LENOVO v: 7LETB0WW (2.10 ) date: 01/21/2008 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 32.5 Wh condition: 39.6/84.2 Wh (47%) 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core2 Duo T7100 bits: 64 type: MCP L2 cache: 2048 KiB 
           Speed: 798 MHz min/max: 800/1801 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 798 2: 798 
Graphics:  Device-1: NVIDIA G86M [Quadro NVS 140M] driver: N/A 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: vesa resolution: 1280x1024~N/A 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0 128 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel 82801H HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-54-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel 82566MM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e 
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 00:1e:37:8e:45:8e 
           Device-2: Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network driver: iwl3945 
           IF: wls3 state: up mac: 00:1c:bf:bc:ef:25 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 74.53 GiB used: 6.12 GiB (8.2%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Hitachi model: HTS541680J9SA00 size: 74.53 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 23.90 GiB used: 5.99 GiB (25.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: /home size: 45.23 GiB used: 137.8 MiB (0.3%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3 
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 3.91 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 81.0 C mobo: 71.0 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): fan-1: 3042 
Info:      Processes: 167 Uptime: 11m Memory: 1.91 GiB used: 620.1 MiB (31.6%) Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.32
```

#### My question

1. How is that even after blacklisting `nouveau`, I still get the GUI?
2. I'm not satisfied with nouveau's limited resolution options and 0 Hz frequency. I get bizzare patterns on my screen. Any help is appreciated.